# In VS Code, how can I change the fonts for the environment? (tab names, side panel, etc)

Tags: visual-studio-code

IN Visual Studio Code, it's easy to change the fonts for the Editor.  What about other things?  Say I wanted to change the fonts for Explorer, the Debug Console, etc.  How can I change those?

Answer (score 0):

**NO, you can`t.** That feature is not likely to be landed in VS Code as well as similar IDEs like Brackets and Atom.
They have in common the ability to change only the workspace font.